# Side of object flickers when the camera is rotated

Tags: three.js

Can someone explain why part of my model flickers black when a material canvas material is added to it and when the camera moves?

Here's a shot of it before an image is added:

[image]

And after when an image has been added and camera rotated:

[image]

Notice the black marks at the top. Is this to do with the material I'm using possibly? Here's how I apply it:

```
for(let i = 0; i < sidesModified.length; i++) {
  let sideName = sidesModified[i];
  let side = this.getSideInLayersObservable(view, sideName);

  let maxAnisotropy = (this.scene && this.scene['renderer']) ? this.scene['renderer'].getMaxAnisotropy() : 2;
  let canvasTexture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(ctx.canvas, THREE.UVMapping, this.scene.materials.wrapS, this.scene.materials.wrapT, THREE.LinearFilter, THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter, THREE.RGBAFormat, THREE.UnsignedByteType, maxAnisotropy);

  for(let j = 0; j < side.length; j++) {
    canvasTexture.wrapS = this.scene.materials.wrapS;
    canvasTexture.wrapT = this.scene.materials.wrapT;
    this._reverseSideIf(this.sceneName, view, sideName, canvasTexture);
    this._drawImageOnCtx(side, j, object, ctx);
  }

  let materialIndex = this.getMaterialIndexForBag(this.sceneName, view, sideName);
  let material = this._setupMaterial(canvasTexture);
  if(this.sceneName === 'two-d-scene') {
    if(view === 'outside') {
      this.selectedBag[0].children[materialIndex].material = material;
    } else {
      this.selectedBag[1].children[materialIndex].material = material;
    }
  } else {
    this.selectedBag.children[materialIndex].material = material
  }
  canvasTexture.needsUpdate = true;
}
```

Comment: It looks like [Z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting)

Comment: Do you have two planes very close together here? For example, when you load your texture, are you placing it on a new plane which rests in nearly the same position/orientation as the side of the bag?

Comment: The model I'm using, which is exported from Blender as an .obj, has each of its sides defined as seperate meshes so I think this may be the thing that is causing, part if not all, the problem. But the flickering only occurs when I add an image.

Comment: So are you guys suggesting that I'll need to fix the object in Blender and readd it to the scene?

Comment: Old issue but maybe it could help others... In this case it looks like z fighting as @Rabbid76 mentionned, the bag seems opaque so set its material transparency to false, it will resolve the issue